# Page not Found after pulling from GitHub in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, github

I have been working on a Project in CodeIgniter 3 and everything is working fine. I have decided to continue the project in **another system**. But when I pulled the project from GitHub into the **second system**, only the **default_controller route** works while **other defined routes** will always redirect me to **404 Page not Foun**d.

I have checked everything from the **first system** and its looking good but I keep getting the Page Not Found! Please any help? ...

Comment: Please, add more details.

Comment: Have you checked if github repository contains all of the code from the first system? If so the problem might be related to the configuration of the 2nd system ie. htaccess or so.

Comment: I will be Checking on the configuration of the 2nd system soon! I will report back when done!